# Do initial setup and allow changes later in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an app and I have the following scenario:

I have one state that needs to take an input from a text box, put it in a local storage variable, put it in an  in another state, and set it as the value in a text box in the third state.

My controller looks like this:

```
angular.module("controllers", ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.controller("appCtrl", function($scope){
    var name = angular.element('.name').val();
    window.localStorage["name"] = name;
    angular.element('h1').text(name);
    angular.element('.other-input').val(name);
})
```

I also tried it the traditional `$scope` way, and it continued to fail:

```
<input ng-value="name" ng-model="name">
<h1>{name}</h1>
```

I would love to hear your suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't play with DOM inside controller..the correct place it to play with DOM is directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope` variables should be bound to the view using **double** curly braces. Try:

```
<input ng-value="name" ng-model="name">
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
```